# Is it possible to check if a bitcoin address "belongs to" a master public key from a deterministic wallet?

Tags: address, bip32-hd-wallets, deterministic-wallets

Let's say I have a Master Public Key (MPK) and have a derived some addresses from it.

How can I check later if a given address was derived from my MPK?

Answer (score 2):

No, except by exhaustively iterating the whole derivation tree below the master.

Answer (score 0):

After I generate the Master-wallet I use the MPK to generate the sub-wallet and the fingerprint and chaincode seems to point to the right master-wallet. I tried using the salt (brain-wallet style) to generate the sub-wallets and this did not match up to the fingerprint or the chain code. hope this works

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with an address only. You need the exact path to the address to generate it. Also make sure what kind of MPK you have, a BIP32 vs [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki).